# What elements in Jetty are pluggable and removale? e.g. session cookies

Tags: java, jetty

I was reading that one of the benefits of Jetty is that many of the layers/modules are either pluggable or removable.

Can someone explain how this works and what modules are pluggable and/or removable?

For example, if I have my own session management in my application, how would I be able to remove session cookies in Jetty?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Jetty very well. But, a session is always optional. You can use
<%@ page session="false" %> in a JSP. A Servlet doesn't create a session unless you add code to do so.

Comment: but tomcat/jetty might look for a session cookie, i want to disable at that level.

Comment: In Tomcat, you can look in it's work folder for the Servlet that is created for a JSP. For a JSP with the page directive that I posted, you can see that a HttpSession object is not even initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Nearly every aspect of Jetty is pluggable.

The best way to see what is available is to first download a distribution and then poke around in the ${jetty.home}/etc/ directory.

Jetty is wired up via a set of xml files found in this directory.

The base xml in the distribution is etc/jetty.xml

If you look at the start.ini you can see which xml files are being referenced by default.

If you want to know more about the OPTIONS parameter and what jar files are being loaded for each, use the following ...

```
$ java -jar start.jar --list-options
```

Don't forget to poke around the other startup command line arguments as well.

```
$ java -jar start.jar --help
```